# Can you use a normal Web Hosting Service to Publish a Flask App?

Tags: flask, web-applications, web-hosting, publishing

I have already purchased a Web Hosting service as well as a domain name which is working to display a static coded website but doesn't let me publish a Flask App. Can someone please explain how to deploy a Flask App to the Internet with a domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosting service needs to support hosting Python applications in the first place. Check out the [deployment section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/#hosted-options) in the Flask documentation for hosted options.

Comment: So if I were to use Heroku instead would I be able to link my existing domain name

Comment: Yeah, for Heroku specifically, follow [this procedure](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).